# What conclusion can we draw?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Let $f \colon Z \to \{-1, 1\}$, where $Z$ denotes the set of integers, be defined by $ f(n) = 1$ if $n$ is even and $f(n) = -1$ if $n$ is odd.

Then we can easily show that $f(m+n) = f(m) \cdot f(n)$ for all $m$, $n \in Z$.

What is the most revealing conclusion that we can draw about the integers?

I know that this mapping is the same as the mapping $g \colon Z \to \{-1,1\}$ defined by $g(n)= (-1)^n$ for all $n \in Z$.

Comment: Why do you expect us to be able to draw any conclusion about the integers from this? The map is simply the usual map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ where we write the latter multiplicatively rather than additively.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I don't think this is such a bad question. The OP has noticed a cool coincidence, and is wondering if there's some conclusion or insight that can be drawn from this coincidence.

Comment: @user18921 I don't think it is a bad question either (I did not downvote). But I wanted to make the OP try to be more precise about why they expected this to lead anywhere, and possibly also what sort of direction they expect it to lead.

Answer (score 4):

About all we can draw from this are the following rules:$\DeclareMathOperator{\even}{even}\DeclareMathOperator{\odd}{odd}$
\begin{align}\even+\even&=\even\\\even+\odd&=\odd\\\odd+\odd&=\even
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

What you have found is called a homomorophism between $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\{\pm1\},\times)$, but I'm not sure if you know what that means yet. These kinds of things are studied in a branch of mathematics called abstract algebra.

A homormophism is a special type of function that respects a particular property. In Algebra, we're mostly interested in homomorphisms that preserve some algebraic structures that arise from the binary operations on two groups. In your example, your homomorphism is preserving the laws of parity on integers and transforms it to the language of signs in $\{\pm 1\}$.

Another example that you might've possibly seen is the map $\exp: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ which has the property $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x).\exp(y)$. Or the inverse map which is $\log: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ which has the property $\log(x.y) = \log(x) + \log(y)$.